# Connect Encoder from AutoEncoder to LSTM

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have an auto encoder defined like this

```
inputs = Input(batch_shape=(1,timesteps, input_dim))

encoded = LSTM(4,return_sequences = True)(inputs)
encoded = LSTM(3,return_sequences = True)(encoded)
encoded = LSTM(2)(encoded)
decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded) 
decoded =  LSTM(3,return_sequences = True)(decoded)                                   
decoded =  LSTM(4,return_sequences = True)(decoded)
decoded =  LSTM(input_dim,return_sequences = True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)

encoder = Model(inputs,encoded)
```

I want the encoder to be connected to a LSTM layer like this

```
f_input = Input(batch_shape=(1, timesteps, input_dim))

encoder_input = encoder(inputs=f_input)

single_lstm_layer = LSTM(50, kernel_initializer=RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05))(encoder_input)
drop_1 = Dropout(0.33)(single_lstm_layer)
output_layer = Dense(12, name="Output_Layer"
                         )(drop_1)

final_model = Model(inputs=[f_input], outputs=[output_layer])
```

But it gives me a dimension error.

> ```
> Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_3: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
> ```

How can I do this properly.?

Comment: The output of encoder (i.e.`encoder_input`) is of shape `(1, 2)`. That's why it cannot be fed to the following LSTM layer.

Comment: Yes. What can I do then.?

Comment: I don't know what the problem you are working on is and why you are doing this, but if ask for resolving this issue in anyway, you must somehow have a Tensor of shape `(1, ?, 2)` to be able to feed it to LSTM layer. To achieve this, one way is to use `RepeatVector` layer on `encoder_input`. However, this may or may not be appropriate thing to do depending on the problem you are working on and the results you want to achieve.

Comment: @today I am trying to do something like this http://eng.uber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Screen-Shot-2017-06-08-at-2.33.18-PM-e1496957645776.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main issue rises up from the fact that the very last `encoded` is not a repeat vector. To feed the encoder output to the LSTM, it needs to be sent through a `RepeatVector` layer. In other words, the last output of the encoder needs to have `[batch_size, time_steps, dim]` shape to be able to be fed into a LSTM. This is probably what you're looking for?

```
inputs = Input(batch_shape=(1,timesteps, input_dim))

encoded = LSTM(4,return_sequences = True)(inputs)
encoded = LSTM(3,return_sequences = True)(encoded)
encoded = LSTM(2)(encoded)
encoded_repeat = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded) 

decoded =  LSTM(3,return_sequences = True)(encoded_repeat)                                   
decoded =  LSTM(4,return_sequences = True)(decoded)
decoded =  LSTM(input_dim,return_sequences = True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)

encoder = Model(inputs,encoded_repeat)

f_input = Input(batch_shape=(1, timesteps, input_dim))

encoder_input = encoder(inputs=f_input)

single_lstm_layer = LSTM(50, kernel_initializer=RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05))(encoder_input)
drop_1 = Dropout(0.33)(single_lstm_layer)
output_layer = Dense(12, name="Output_Layer"
                         )(drop_1)

final_model = Model(inputs=[f_input], outputs=[output_layer])
```

I have renamed your first `decoded` to `encode_repeat`

Comment: this is what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code already gives the answer.
`encoder` has in its last layer lstm with two dimension (number_batch, number_features) instead of (number_batches, number_timesteps, number_features).
This is because you did not set `return_sequences = True`(this is your intended behaviour).

But what you want to do is the same, as what you do with your decoder: You apply the RepeatVector layer to make the input shape 3 dimensional and therefore able to be feeded into a LSTM Layer.

Comment: So, I want to change the encoder decoder archtecture.?

Comment: Yes if the encoded representation is meant to be fed inside another lstm layer then it would make sense to encode to a 3 dimesnional shape. So simply put `return_sequences = True` in your third lstm layer and delete the Repeat Vector Layer.